# Store type in variable to use like a type later

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to store a type in a variable so that I can use it like a 1st class type later on.

```
class SomeModel {}

let someType = SomeModel.self
let array = Array<someType>()
```

In this case sure I could have done `Array<SomeModel>()` instead but I want to generalize it and let subclasses provide the value of `someType`.

However I get errors like `someType isn't a type` or `use of undeclared type 'someType'` on the last line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
func someFunc<T>(model: T) -> Array<T> {
    let array = Array<T>()
    return array
}

let someType = SomeModel.self
let array = someFunc(someType())
```

Looks like this does what I want. The only drawback is that I have to create an instance of the desired type to pass. In this case its minimal overhead, but it just seems like a waste.

Another thing with using generics like this is it appears that the generic's possible types are computed at compile time, so at run time `model.dynamicType` doesn't necessarily match `T`. In most cases it will, but if you are doing any reflection driven stuff make sure to really check your use case well.

Comment: You need not create an instance, you can simply `func someFunc<T>(model: T.Type) -> Array<T> {...`

Answer (score 16):

If you need to store several type values in array, this works pretty well:

```
let array: [Any.Type] = [String.self, Int.self]
```

Comment: How do I retrieve it to cast objects into types though? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

These days, this can be more easily and adaptably achieved by using `.Type` on a class or protocol. Note that only functions available to that root class or protocol will be accessible however, so you should ensure that a required initialiser of some kind is defined. For example:

```
protocol MyClass {
   init(someValue: Int)
}

class MyWrapper {

   let myClassType: MyClass.Type

   init(classType: MyClass.Type) {
      self.myClassType = classType
   }

   func new(with value: Int) -> MyClassType {
      return MyClassType.init(someValue: value)
   }

}
```

You can now initialise this rather silly factory class with a specific class implementing the MyClass protocol and when you call the `new()` function with an integer value it will generate a new instance of that class and return it.